# Yocto Bluetooth HFP: headset_audio_gateway not available

Tags: sound, kernel, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'll just jump straight to it...

I'm currently using a Yocto image:

Linux kernel version 4.14

PulseAudio v11.1

oFono v1.19

BlueZ v5.43

I have successfully managed to get the HFP working on linux kernel version 4.13. However with the 4.14 kernel version and the software versions shown above...
Whenever I list the pulseaudio cards, the a2dp profile is available however the headset_audio_gateway profile is not available.

Whenever I try to switch to the profile, it says Input/Output error.
The command I use is #pactl set-card-profile 1 headset_audio_gateway

I can play audio using the a2dp profile over bluetooth after connecting to my mobile phone through blueZ.

Can anyone help/guide me to finding out why HFP is saying "available: no" ?

I'd really appreciate any help provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable modem after the connection:

```
/usr/lib/ofono/test/enable-modem
```